# I2C communication with LCD2041 using PIC32MM

Tags: pic, i2c, embedded, lcd, mplab

I am trying to communicate with LCD2041 using pic32MM using I2C I wrote the following code on MPLAB code configurator but so far the status for the I2c communication seems to get stuck on pending . I need help on how I can proceed further . The default slave address for LCD is 0x50

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
//#include "lcd_i2c.h"

#define slave_Adress 0b01010000 

void ByteDelay(void){
    // Delay between bytes required by LCD2041 spec
    DELAY_microseconds(625);
}

void ReadDelay(void){
    // Delay between read commands required by LCD2041 spec
    DELAY_milliseconds(3);
}

void TransactionDelay(void){
    // Delay between transactions required by LCD2041 spec
    DELAY_microseconds(375);
}

int main(void)
{
   SYSTEM_Initialize();
   uint8_t data = 0xFE; // host to tell data are output via I2c   
   uint8_t lcd_clear_display =  0xA4; // command    to clear LCD
   TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 1; // set B2 (scl) as input 
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 1; // set B3 (SDA) as input 
    
   I2C2_Initialize() ;   
   I2C2_MESSAGE_STATUS status ; 
   I2C2_MasterWrite(data, 1 , slave_Adress, &status);
    ByteDelay();
    if ( status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING) {led_3_SetHigh();} 
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Ideally check the I2C lines themselves with a scope or cheap USB-based logic analyzer.  Do you have pull-up resistors?  Is your peripheral powered?  Even without any ack from the peripheral you should see some electrical activity on the bus...   Also try it with a many orders of magnitude longer delay; really you might as well try an eternel loop in initial debugging, though giving up at some point is indeed a good idea in the long run.

Comment: yes i have a pull up resistor of 3.2 K , while scoping i can see some signal for SDA but not for SCL

Comment: Sounds like a clue.  Try to figure out if it's shorted, not enabled, or...